# updating matplotlib plot in pyqt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I'm trying to make a gui which involves plotting some functions, but I can't get the plots to update. I've tried a few ideas, but haven't got anything to work. I initially tried putting the updatePlot in the updatePlot function so it would run in a kind of loop, but it kept crashing. This is a simplified version of my most recent attempt.

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        #adding buttons, boxes, labels...

        self.fig = None
        self.ax = None
        self.x = np.arange(-10,10,0.01)
    
        self.plotButton.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.updatePlotButton.clicked.connect(self.plotUpdate)

    def quad_cubic(self):
        c0value = float(self.c0.text())
        c1value = float(self.c1.text())
        c2value = float(self.c2.text())
        c3value = float(self.c3.text())
        y2 = c0value + c1value*self.x + c2value*self.x**2
        y3 = c0value + c1value*self.x + c2value*self.x**2 + c3value*self.x**3
        return y2,y3

    def run(self):
        self.fig,self.ax = plt.subplots(2,1,dpi = 150)
        self.plotUpdate()
    
    def plotUpdate(self):
        y2,y3 = self.quad_cubic()
        self.ax[0].cla()
        self.ax[1].cla()
        self.ax[0].plot(self.x,y2)
        self.ax[1].plot(self.x,y3)      
        plt.show(block = False)
```

Comment: Kept crashing how? Is there an error in the output?

Comment: I just tested again with the update in the function. The issue was that if you triggered the update, it would often run many times, and I had to add a plt.pause to actually make it update, and if you tried to update while it was in this loop it would crash. It seemed the more times you clicked update the more loops it would run.

Comment: Actually, if I add a plt.pause and run it outside the function, it seems to work, thanks